# AJAX call for refreshing not getting data- value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a chatbox for my website but when I try to get a data- value my result is undefined. My javascript calls the AJAX to my fetchChat.php as so...

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () {refreshChat()}, 5000);

function refreshChat() {
    var lastItem = 0;
    lastItem = $(".chatmessage:last-child").data('value');
    if (typeof lastItem === 'undefined')
    {
        alert("undefined");
        lastItem = 0;
    }

    $.post("outputPages/fetchChat.php", {'li':lastItem}, function(response)
    {   
        $(".messagefeed").append(response);
    });
}
```

And my PHP in fetchChat is:

```
<?PHP
require "../pages/connect.php";

$li = $_POST;
$li = implode($li);

$fetch = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE messageID >= '$li' ORDER BY messageID ";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($fetch)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $ID = $row['messageID'];
        $date = $row['messageDate'];
        $persona = $row['messagePersona'];
        $message = htmlspecialchars($row['message'], ENT_QUOTES);
        echo "<p class='chatmessage' data-value='$ID'>$date $persona:     $message</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

So basically I use the data-value of the last message to get all messages greater than the last message. But whenever I echo lastItem in javascript it returns undefined. Any help is really appreciated! This is my own idea and Im trying to see what I can do with my school knowledge so far.

Comment: Have you tried $(".chatmessage:last-child").attr('data-value') to see what you get. Also, have you tests $(".chatmessage:last-child").length to see if you have a valid selector?

Comment: That was it! Your first answer $(".chatmessage:last-child").attr('data-value') fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I have to change my lastItem to $(".chatmessage:last-child").attr('data-value');

Thank you Roumelis for the help!

Comment: No problem. You tried to access html attribute with jQuery's .data(). If you want to use .data() you have to set the data-attribute with the same function first.